# Find in JSON array

Tags: php, json, find

Need help with array search in JSON. I found how to find a complete match. But I did not find it as a partial match.

```
[{"id":"b34ec69d-a183-4fe2-a69e-9c1ef4286045","name":"Communication","location":"Room 1"},
{"id":"65931d66-b703-4c61-9303-94836eb682fc","name":"Finance","location":"Room 2"},
{"id":"f3bed216-e60c-4691-a465-87f1ae28914a","name":"Business","location":"Room 3"}]
```

```php
function findOst($a)
{
  $json_url = "*****";
  if(get_http_response_code($json_url) == '200') {
    $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $links = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    $expected = array_filter($links, function ($var) use ($a) {
      return ($var['name'] == $a);
    });

    foreach ($expected as $item) {
        echo strval($item['name']);
        echo "<br>";
        echo strval($item['id']);
        echo "<hr><br>";
    }
  }
  else{
    echo "No data";
  }
}

findOst('Finance');
//Find and Show: Finance
```

Need find: 'in' in array JSON

```php
findOst('in');
```

To find all the meanings in which there is a part of the word. And get: Finance, Business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strstr()` to search for a partial match.

```
    $expected = array_filter($links, function ($var) use ($a) {
      return strstr($var['name'], $a);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yesterday, half a night I spoiled it.